# CPLEX: dvar declaration with conditions

Tags: cplex

I am using CPLEX and declaring the dvar with the following:

```
dvar int+ Y[i in a][j in a][m in b] in 0..1
```

I do not want to create a variable when i = j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable indexer are not allowed but you have 3 workarounds:

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexertupleset.mod
https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexerdexpr.mod
https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexerunion.mod

The first one is the most used and for your case this gives:

```
{int} a={1,2};
{int} b={4,5};

tuple t
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

{t} ijs={<i,j> | i,j in a:i!=j};

//dvar int+ Y[i in a][j in a][m in b] in 0..1

dvar int+ Y[ij in ijs][m in b] in 0..1;

subject to
{
  Y[<1,2>][4]==1;
}
```